# Need to maintain some data in browser even cache cleared

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, indexeddb, metamask

I need to maintain some data in browser like local-storage, session-storage, Cookies, Indexed-db. But the stored data would not be cleared(erased or deleted) even clear the cache and history of the browser. Is there is way to stored it ? Please share your Knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a way. If there was, it would run contrary to the browser's privacy guarantees to the user - the user is explicitly asking for that data to be removed - and it would be a bug that browser vendors would quickly fix.

You need to come up with another storage approach outside of the browser. One is to store the data server-side, tied to credentials. The other is to allow the data to be downloaded/saved by the user to the filesystem, and then allow re-uploading back to the site.

Comment: ok make sense, but how metamask extension has been worked they are not erasing the data and the data couldn't be viewed in browser.

Comment: chrome extensions have their own separate data storage. it can still be cleared.